# Can't find where the do_action("This function") leads to in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in my `index.php` file. It adds the home banner image in WordPress. I know that it is mostly generated in WordPress customizer, but I need to add an anchor tag in this section. I can't find it anywhere in the file structure.

```
<?php do_action('cleanblog_index_top'); ?>
```

I'm not able to find where `cleanblog_index_top` leads to. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Look in your `functions.php`

Comment: I basically need to see where the html content for 'cleanblog_index_top' is stored so that I can edit it I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I searched for it in the functions.php file and it came up with nothing

Comment: Then search your entire wordpress directory for `cleanblog_index_top`, your IDE should be able to do that

Comment: I searched the entire project in vscode and it's only mentioned once in the index.php file. Is this area totally created by the customizer tool and the customizer.js file? I see it's binding the values from the customizer tool to an h1 tag and a span tag in the js file but I thought that was just for ajax live preview stuff I just can't find where they are.

Comment: It could be a hook for you with no default functions hooked to it too.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this old one while looking up the docs for `do_action()`. The answers are brutal so I decided to provide a better answer in case anyone else stumbles here.

If a WordPress theme has something like `do_action( 'example_action_hook_tag' )` somewhere in one of the template files (such as `index.php`, `page.php` or whatever) the purpose is to provide theme or plugin authors with a way to write their own custom function that they can then "hook" onto the action with the function `add_action()`.

WordPress would then call this function any time and anywhere `do_action( 'example_action_hook_tag' )` is called.

The creators of commercial themes will often litter their template files with hooks declared with `do_action()` to make it easier for their customers to customize their themes via `functions.php` or by writing a site-specific plugin.

It looks to me that this is the likely scenario that is impacting the OP. This also explains why the OP was unsuccessful in finding where this "leads to".

It would only "lead somewhere" if the OP wrote a function in the theme/child-theme `functions.php` or in a plugin and added the line `do_action( 'cleanblog_index_top', 'name_of_ops_function' )` to hook their function onto the *cleanblog_index_top*. WordPress would then call their function when `do_action( 'cleanblog_index_top' )` was called in `index.php`.

From the name of the OP's hook, `cleanblog_index_top`, it sounds like the theme author intended to provide a way for others to inject output at the top of the index page template.

Suppose the OP wanted `<h1>Hello World</h1>` to appear there.

In `functions.php` of a theme/child-theme the OP could add a function that echo's this out:

```php
function op_customization() {
  echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
}
```

And hook their function onto *cleanblog_index_top*:

```php
add_action( 'cleanblog_index_top', 'op_customization' );
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should never edit the index.php file directly, for the same reason you should never edit core Wordpress files directly - the next time WP pushes an update, your changes will be overwritten (and that assumes you don't break anything). Never edit plugin files directly, same reason.

You need to look in your theme, you should only make changes to the functions.php and style.css files in your theme - unless you create a child theme and that is a topic you should Google.

Comment: Index.php is literally the front page though, you can edit it without any issues

Comment: Until Wordpress updates, then your changes will most-probably be overwritten.

Comment: Nope, index.php isn't affected by core updates. All of my sites use it as the front page, nothing gets removed.

Comment: Are you talking about a WP theme index.php file Andy, or a child-theme index.php file? There's been a lot of talk about index.php w/out much effort to clarify that. Any index.php file not in a child theme remains subject to being ovewritten because of updates.

Comment: Theme index.php, which is what the OP is on about - https://github.com/deviodigital/cleanblog

Comment: In that case: changes to the theme index.php file are subject to clobbering when the theme updates. If the theme developer makes changes to that file, the local changes disappear when the theme updates. If the theme dev doesn't alter that file, local changes may or may not be overwritten - depending on whether the update is a patch or a complete working copy of the theme.

Which is why I'm seconding the recommendation that a child theme be generated and said changes be placed there instead.